# ¿Cómo llamar a la función no definida sqlsrv_connect () al realizar la conexión a un servidor sql?

Tags: php

> Error no detectado: Llame a la función no definida sqlsrv_connect ()

Al tratar de hacer una conexión a la base de datos del servidor sql. en la carpeta de xampp \ php \ ext agregué los siguientes drivers:

```
 php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll 
php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll
php_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
```

Luego en *php.ini* ingrese lo siguiente:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts.dll
extension=php-sqlsrv_73_ts.dll
```

pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Answer (score 0):

Bueno te dejo un [articulo](http://www.latindevelopers.com/articulo/como-configurar-php-para-acceder-a-bases-de-datos-sql-server/) del 2017 para hacer una conexión de php con sqlserver.

En resumen tienes que ir probando las versiones de los conectores, que sean compatibles con el SO 32 o 64 bits .

Se requiere los dos archivos de librerías, dependiendo de la [versión](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver15) de tu PHP, para mi caso:

-Descargar SQLSRV32.exe (copiar: php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll, php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll) en la ruta: C:\XAMPP\PHP\EXT\

-Otro dato importante es instalar  SQL Server ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server, según versión 32bit o 64bit de S.O. Windows

Esto se hizo con el siguiente ambiente.
-PHP Version 5.6.23
-Apache 2.4.17
-XAMPP Control Panel Version 3.2.2

Cuando acabes crea un archivo info.php y pon lo siguiente:

```
<?php
    phpinfo(); 
?>
```

y llámala desde tu navegador:
deberia salirte lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias bro, voy a probar

Comment: ya me sale sqlsrv en el pdo de php.ini .pero me sigue saliendo el siguiente error .Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp2\htdocs\sqlPrueba\prueba.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\sqlPrueba\prueba.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

1) Lo primero de todo es instalar [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)

2) Luego asegurate de tener instalados los [Drivers de PHP para SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) con la versión correcta dependiendo de la versión de PHP que estés usando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]